# Display the max amount and corresponding branch name using max() SQL?

Tags: sql, max

My table would be like 
[image: this image]

I need an output like: [image: this image]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a subquery:

```
select * from YourTable
where amount IN (select Max(amount) from YourTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Ammount in (SELECT MAX(Ammount) FROM Products );
```

-OR-

```
SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY Ammount DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

select loan_id, branch, amount 
from branch
where branch.amount = (select max(s.amount) from branch s)

this will get you multiple rows if multiple branches have the same amount of course. 
yea, and the other answer that got posted while I was writing:)